# Java MouseListener in a Class

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, mouselistener, swingx

I am new to Java and would like to achieve the following.

I have a various `comboboxes`. For each `combobox` I have a button that should clear the content of the combobox. The clear buton is created from a generic `ClearComboBoxButton` class that I have created. As part of this `ClearComboBoxButton` class I want to add a `MouseListener` that will clear the `combobox` associated with it.

When I create my button the associated `combobox` is passed as a parameter.

This is what I have at the moment. (My button is created successfully but the `listener` does not seem to fire)

```
public class ClearComboBoxButton extends JXButton implements MouseListener{
private JXComboBox cboComboBox;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public ClearComboBoxButton(JXComboBox cboComboBox){
    super();        
    this.setCboComboBox(cboComboBox);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    setToolTipText("Clear");
    setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Java\\icons\\cancel.png"));
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0, JXComboBox cboComboBox) { 
    System.out.println("Cleared");
    this.setCboComboBox(cboComboBox);
    cboComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);   
}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public JXComboBox getCboComboBox() {
    return cboComboBox;
}
public void setCboComboBox(JXComboBox cboComboBox) {
    this.cboComboBox = cboComboBox;
}
}
```

Comment: Your button needs to add itself as a mouse listener (`this.addMouseListener(this)`).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `mouseClicked()` method doesn't do anything:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Second, in order for your listener to be called, it should be added to the component which fires mouse events, and that you want to listen to. Since your button wants to be aware of the events fired by itself, you need

```
this.addMouseListener(this);
```

**But** you should never use a `MouseListener` to listen to button clicks. An `ActionListener` should be used for that. First because it's simpler, and more correct, semantically. Second, because many users use their keyboard to click a button.

I would personally avoid extending JXButton, and use composition instead. And I would also use an anonymous class as the listener, rather than making your class implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Your event source (Button) needs to *register* an event handler in order to receive mouse events. Since your Button implements MouseListener, you can register `this` as your listener:

```
public ClearComboBoxButton(JXComboBox cboComboBox){
    super();        
    this.setCboComboBox(cboComboBox);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
    setToolTipText("Clear");
    setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Java\\icons\\cancel.png"));

    this.addMouseListener(this); // add this line
}
```